# Finding critical values of a trig function with cubes

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$f(x) = 4sin^3(x) - 3cos^2(x)$$ On the interval $[0,2π]$

So on the endpoints, I think I that $f(0) = -3$ and $f(2π) = -3$ (Correct me if my algebra is wrong here:)

$$f(0) = 4(sin(0))^3 - 3(cos(0))^2 = -3$$ and likewise with $2π$

So, to find the critical numbers, I had gotten the derivative as follows:
$$6\cos x\sin x(2\sin x+1)$$
And as critical numbers, I believe $x=0, \frac{7\pi}{6},\frac{11\pi}{6}$

I think my algebra may be wrong here again:
$$[2\sin x+1]$$
$$\sin x = -\frac12$$

Am I correct in finding my critical numbers? If so, to find the max/min values all I have to do is simply plug in all these values and see which one is the highest/lowest?

Thanks

Comment: The endpoint-values are correct. The derivate is correct as well.

Comment: The (possible) critical locations are $k\pi$ and $(k+\frac{1}{2})\pi$ , $-\frac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi$ and finally $-\frac{5}{6}\pi+2k\pi$, where $k$ is an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your endpoint values are correct.

Your derivative is correct.

Your mistake is in calculating the roots of the derivative. Remember, $a\cdot b=0$ it $a=0$ **or** if $b=0$.

So, in your case, $$6\cos x \sin x (2\sin x + 1) = 0$$
if $\cos x = 0$, or if $\sin x = 0$, or if $\sin x =-\frac12$.

---

So, you still have two options to analyze.

Comment: Wouldn't this give me quite a bit of critical points? With those 3 if conditions I'd get quite abit. Am I to respect all of those points?

Comment: @user382540 There aren't *that* many. It shouldn't take more than 10 minutes to identify all the critical points, and look at the value of $f$ at those points. Am I to believe you consider 10 minute too much?